# Need a query to find total distance with some condition?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in my database, One is category and second is an entry table.

My Category Table is like below:

```
----------------------------------
| Cat_ID |  cat_type | cat_value |
----------------------------------
|  201   |  running  |     1     |
|  202   |  cycling  |     4     |
----------------------------------
```

My Entry Table is like below:

```
-------------------------------
| user_id | cat_ID | distance |
-------------------------------
|    1    |   201  |    50    |
|    1    |   201  |    50    |
|    1    |   202  |   100    |
|    1    |   202  |   100    |
|    2    |   201  |    10    |
|    2    |   201  |    10    |
-------------------------------
```

So Now I want to total distance for user ID "1" but here one condition is that for  201 categories the sum of the total will divide by one and for 202 category total distance will divide by 4 as per category table in cat_value.

Means i want total distance like ((50+50)/1 + (100+100)/4)

So, how can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried? :-) SO isn't a free coding service, we can help you debug, but we won't create the code for you.

Comment: "_So, how can i do this?_" You can start by researching, then coding this and getting back here with code if it fails somewhere. We're not gonna code this for you.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I know it is not free coding service. I have tried much code but not able to get the result. So, finally, i put the question here without code because i am not sure that what code will give my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join and sub-query

```
select 
    sum(t1.totald/c.cat_value) as total_distance
from 
    cat c
join
    (select 
         sum(distance) totald, user_id, cat_id 
     from 
         entry where user_id=1 --- if you just want for userid=1
     group by 
         user_id, cat_id) t1 on c.Cat_ID = t1.Cat_ID
```

Comment: Giving code to people who didn't make the effort to try themselves will encourage that behavior of theirs.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy not interested to any argument just mind it im not new here :)

Comment: Just stating a fact, new or not, I would have said the same thing to anyone. Cheers!

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Personally I don't see why it would require a downvote on an answer for that reason.  I see posts without a first attempt from the OP all the time. Sometimes they just don't know where to start.  And in this case the OP actually added some sample data without being asked.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin thanks for help me, but this code giving me null result as i have run this,

Comment: @SantoshKhatri can you give me  fiddle link where you ran this query

Comment: @SantoshKhatri https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a3ba7d04c1f57e998a3f6b413c4a8f5 check the link please i have done for your sample data

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin yes it is working but the answer is coming wrong. the answer should be 150 instead of 170.

Comment: @SantoshKhatri https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc3c989adcea72cbb0530dbdb6120235 yes it is 150 as i did impose condition so that was check this link it is 150  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc3c989adcea72cbb0530dbdb6120235

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Yes my superman, it is working. thanks a lot dear. you save my life.